# Using Vinegar to Cut down on Spice

Tags: sauce, spices, vinegar

I've read recommendations on cutting down the spice of a sauce using butter, oil, fat, yogurt, and cream; however, I've tried all those and they don't seem to do the same type of balancing as adding vinegar.

Is this just my tastebuds being weird or is there something "to" adding vinegar to cut down on spice heat?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can't tell you *why* it works - possibly alteration of sodium or calcium channel response in the taste receptors? - but I've seen Indian cooks use lemon or lime juice in much the same way to cut down the heat of a too-hot curry. It's definitely [a done thing](http://www.seriouseats.com/2011/01/what-to-do-when-you-add-too-much-spice-make-less-spicy.html).

Comment: Thanks! I didn't even think about lemon juice. Cool! And thanks for the link :)

Comment: You're welcome! My wife prefers lime juice over lemon as she finds it harmonizes better with curries.